# How to convert special key codes of a pynput listener

Tags: python, keylogger, pynput

My problem is when I listen to a key combination of like `Ctrl + V` the key logger shows me that the pressed keys are `[Ctrl, '\x16']` (I am showing it on an array).

So, my question is, Can someone tell me a way of converting this key code to the right one or another way of achieving the final result?